# Detekt setting for exclude is ignored

Tags: android, yaml, config, detekt

How can I exclude the sample folder from the following rules? with this configuration it is not working and detekt keeps parsing the sample folder

```
UndocumentedPublicClass:
  active: true
  excludes: &samples
    - '**/rd/compose/samples/**'
  includes: &composeComponent
    - '**/rd/compose/**'
UndocumentedPublicFunction:
  active: true
  excludes: *samples
  includes: *composeComponent
OutdatedDocumentation:
  active: true
  excludes: *samples
  includes: *composeComponent
  allowParamOnConstructorProperties: true
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

There is [a bug](https://github.com/detekt/detekt/issues/5728) in Detekt that prevents configurations like yours from working: the `excludes` path filters are not evaluated if `includes` are present. [The fix](https://github.com/detekt/detekt/pull/5782) has just been implemented and is currently in the [1.23.0 milestone](https://github.com/detekt/detekt/milestone/88?closed=1). Let's hope for a release soon. Unfortunately, the logic seems to have been in place for years so reverting to a previous release is probably not an option.

### Workaround:

While we wait for that fix, consider *implicitly* excluding `samples/` by *explicitly* including all other direct subfolders and files within `compose/`. For example:

```
UndocumentedPublicClass:
  active: true
  includes: &composeComponentNotSamples
    - '**/rd/compose/folderA/**'
    - '**/rd/compose/folderB/**'
    - '**/rd/compose/fileC.kt'
    - '**/rd/compose/fileD.kt'
UndocumentedPublicFunction:
  active: true
  includes: *composeComponentNotSamples
OutdatedDocumentation:
  active: true
  includes: *composeComponentNotSamples
  allowParamOnConstructorProperties: true
```

This should do the trick but should only be considered as a temporary solution because it would require manual effort to update that list as you add, rename, or remove files & folders.